# How to get the key value pair in multiple check checkbox in android

Tags: android, listview, mobile, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am new to android, can anybody please help to get the key and corresponding value(check/not-check) in a checkbox.

There can be more than one checked item in checkbox. I have to get all the items for which user has "checked" in the checkbox. I am using the following code in "onCheckedChanged".

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
        //String temp = viewHolder.checkbox.getText().toString(); //didn't give me the key
        //Log.d(TAG, temp);
        //String temp = buttonView.getText().toString(); //didn't give me the key
        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Comment: When you paste in code, please do not use `Tabs` for indentation it doesn't format correctly

Answer (score 0):

You get passed the control that changed state in the buttonView parameter. Why don't you just save pointers to the controls in onCreate, using findViewByiD(), and then compare to said pointers in onCheckedChange?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get your solution. I am using arrayAdapter for displaying the checkbox. Following is code of the arrayAdapter which handles "setOnCheckedChangeListener"

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;
private static final String TAG = "InteractiveArrayAdapter";

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                        //String temp = viewHolder.checkbox.getText().toString();
                        //Log.d(TAG, temp);
                        //String temp = buttonView.getText().toString();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {

        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you were looking for a way of tracking all the checked boxes in your list? if so try something like the following

```
private ArrayList<boolean> checkedList = new ArrayList<boolean>();

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if (isChecked && !checkedList.contains(list.getPosition()))
          checkedList.add(list.getPosition());
       else if (!isChecked && checkedList.contains(list.getPosition()))   
          //TODO search and remove list item here
    }
});

return convertView;
```

}